# Call redirect on extended class in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have extended [SubmittedForm](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/blob/master/code/model/submissions/SubmittedForm.php) of class so i can add my logic after theform submmits.

You can see the function [updateAfterProcess](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/blob/master/code/model/UserDefinedForm.php#L790) in my `DataExtension`, everything works fine except I want to redirect from here in this function.

```
    class MyForm extends DataExtension
    {

        static $db = array();

        public function updateAfterProcess(){
            // $this->redirect('www.google.com');
            // want to redirect here 
        }
    }

SubmittedForm:
  default_sort: 'Created DESC'
  extensions:
    - MyForm
```

Comment: You should be able to use `$this->redirect(...)` unless you have a `redirect` function in your class. You can also give `parent::redirect(...)` a try.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DataExtension::redirect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/freelottofest/mysite/code/extensions/SurveyForm.php on line 20

Comment: @Peter i have also used Director::redirect('/placements'); but didn't work.

Comment: Is the `DataExtension` class having a namespace? And are you sure that `DataExtension` has a method `redirect` that is not private?

Comment: No silver strip doesn't support namespace

Comment: Try `$this->owner->redirect(...)`

Comment: @3dgoo tried same error

Comment: `Member::redirect(...)` doesn't do the trick either?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Member::redirect() @Peter  :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SubmittedForm` is a `DataObject` and not a `Controller`. Therefore it also doesn't have the `redirect` method.

I think your best bet is to use `Controller::curr()`, which will get the current controller.

Example:

```
Controller::curr()->redirect(/* where you wanna go */);
```

Comment: Worked Thanks a lot :) @bummzack